# ACL's Centos Linux - Not being inherited

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, file-permissions

Trying to work out the needed ACL's...
OS is Centos Linux

Situation:

Folder called home.

User called user1 and User called user2.

user1 owns folder home, user2 has RWX to home also.

With ACL's Im trying to make it so that when user1 creates a file/folder in home,
that user2 is also given RWX permissions to it.
Also when user2 creates a file/folder in home that user1 is given RWX permissions to it.

ACLS I have tried:

```
getfacl home
user:user1:rwx
user:user2:rwx
default:user1:rwx
default:user2:rwx
```

However when a new file is created it shows

```
getfacl home/testfolder
# owner: user1
# group: AllUsers
user::rwx
user:user1:rwx          #effective:r-x
user:user2:rwx          #effective:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:47:rwx
default:user:48:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

The permissions are being inherited, but it appears the write access is being removed?
Creating a separate group to allow this isn't an option.

Has anyone tried something similar and got it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just played around with this a bit...

What's the ACL (default) mask for the home/ directory?
It should be 'rwx' for this to work.
You can set it with:

```
setfacl -m d:m:rwx home
```

Also you will have to change the mask for the testfolder (as it is 'r-w' right now):

```
setfacl -m m:rwx home/testfolder
```

Hope that helps.